# I need assistance with flex:1 in Css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to use flex:1 in CSS without success, Yes I have used display flex on the parent, and using the flex:1 on this child why I am not being able to see a result?

```
<Link to={`/chat/${name}`}>
<div className="chat">
    <Avatar className="chat__image" alt={name} src={profilePic} />
 <div className="chat__details">
     <h2>{name}</h2>
     <p>{message}</p>
 </div>
    <p className="chat__timestamp">{timestamp}</p>
</div>
</Link>
```

and here is the CSS for what I'm talking about

```
.chat {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 20px;
height: 70px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;
```

}

```
.chat__details {
flex: 1;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should post your rendered HTML. What result are you expecting? You say it's not working, but we have no idea what you want. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried "flex-grow: 1" ?

Comment: I think the default for flex is to be `row` and you haven't given the parent a width. Either give it a width or switch `flex-direction` to `column`